# fallback css grid is not working

Tags: html, css

I was recommended to combine css-grid and css-table via "@support" in following way: browsers supporting grid should use grid and browsers not supporting grid fall back on the default table-style.

Now it seems, that my grid-layout just can't be established, even if ff is responding to @support (e.g. one of the two links, who should change in grid-mode changed). Anyone an idea what is wrong with my code?

Here is the what I still get

[DEFAULT TABLE FALLBACK] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfQNl.jpg)

here is what I want

[DESIRED GRID LAYOUT] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5v4v.jpg)

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: my issue (as described above) is now solved (as you can see below).. deleted my first snippet, cause the better working one is below now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `.wrapper-of-wrapper {  display: none;}` to before the `@supports` starts.
I think this will help you:

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /*some definitions */
}

.grid-G-and-H {
  display: none;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  mso-hide: all;
}

.wrapper-of-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

/*- - - - - - - - @supports - - - - - - - - - - - - */

@supports (display: grid) {
  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .wrapper-of-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .wrapper {
    height: auto;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 16% 16% 16%;
    -ms-grid-rows: 10% 10% 10%;
    flex: 0;
    grid-column-gap: 7px;
    grid-row-gap: 7px;
    grid-template-columns: 16% 16% 16%;
    justify-content: center;
    /*horizontal*/
    align-content: center;
    /*vertical*/
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  }
  .box {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: grey;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .a {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    border: 5px solid red;
  }
  .b {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .c {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .d {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3;
  }
  .e {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 3;
  }
  .f {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
  }
  .grid-G-and-H {
    display: block;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /*some definitions*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="G">
  <!--absolute positioned-->
  <a href="link.html"><img style="margin: auto; width: 23px; height: 27px; left: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0pt; bottom: 0pt;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/23x27"></a>
</div>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<div>
  <a href="link.html"><img style="max-width: 600px; max-hight: 400px; width: 65%; height: auto; border: 5px solid red" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x400"></a>
</div>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<div id="H">
  <!--absolute positioned-->
  <a href="link.html"><img style="margin: auto; width: 23px; height: 27px; right: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0pt; bottom: 0pt;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/23x27"></a>
</div>
<!-- ## END OF DIVS FOR TABLE###### -->
<!-- ## BEGINNING OF DIVS FOR GRID ## -->
<div class="grid-G-and-H">
  <div id="G_grid">
    <a href="changed-link.html"><img style="margin: auto; width: 23px; height: 27px; left: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0pt; bottom: 0pt;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/23x27"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<div class="wrapper-of-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box a" id="A">
      <img style="color: red" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
    </div>
    <div class="box b" id="B">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
    </div>
    <div class="box c" id="C">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
    </div>
    <div class="box d" id="D">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
    </div>
    <div class="box e" id="E">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
    </div>
    <div class="box f" id="F">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<div class="grid-G-and-H">
  <div id="H_grid">
    <a href="changed-link.html"><img style="margin: auto; width: 23px; height: 27px; left: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0pt; bottom: 0pt;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/23x27"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah this is something, thanks! In this case image A from table was laying behind the grid view. So I also added id="A" to the image A in html-table-section and made it display: none in the css-grid-section. Now it works fine. Now I must see, how to change the links for G and H....

Comment: PS: ok, concerning the link-change-issue. I worked with ids here too in order to change the links by swapping the divs. Works fine. Reason for only one link working was an overlay of the wrapper. Solved it with z-index..perfect now, I am happy about beeing supported here so fast !